# Reverse Engineering Fixed Point Numbers

Tags: embedded, fixed, point, notation

I am currently putting an engine into another car and I want to keep the fuel economy calulation inside the boardcomputer working. I managed to recode this part sucessfully, but I have been trying to figure out the (simple?) two byte dataformat they used without success. I assume it is fixed point notation, but no matter how I shift it around, it does not line up. How do the two bytes represent the right number?

```
Some examples:

Bytes (Dec) --> Result
174,10 -> 2,67 
92,11  -> 2,84
128,22 -> 3,75
25,29  -> 4,85
225,23 -> 3,98 
00,40  -> 5,00 
128,34 -> 5,75
```

Comment: Is the left-hand side supposed to be two separate integer numbers and the right-hand side a floating-point number?

Comment: Yes, I edited my post to make it clearer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a partial solution:

First, swap the bytes. Then join them:

The result (in hex) is:

```
0AAE
0B5C
1680
1D19
17E1
2800
2280
```

Then split the into the first digit (4 bits), the remaining three digits (12 bits) and keep the entire number (16 bits) as well. The result (in decimal) is:

```
0  2734   2734
0  2908   2908
1  1664   5760
1  3353   7449
1  2017   6113
2  2048  10240
2   640   8832
```

The first digits seems to be a multiplication factor. 0 stands for 1024, 1 for 1536, 2 for 2048. The formula possibly is `f = (1024 + n * 512)`.

Now divide the entire number by the multiplication factor. The result, rounded to two decimal places, is:

```
 2734 / 1024 =  2.67
 2908 / 1024 =  2.84
 5760 / 1536 =  3.75
 7449 / 1536 =  4.85
 6113 / 1536 =  3.98
10240 / 2048 =  5.00
 8832 / 2048 =  4.31
```

It works for all except the last number, which might contain a mistake.

So it seems to be some sort of floating-point number but I don't recoginze the specific format. Possibly, there is a simpler formula the explains the number.

Comment: Thank you very much, this got me on the right track! Its actually much easier: For each 5000 step the divisor gets increased by 512, then the last value is also correct. So the formula is something like this:  (float)combinedNumber/(1024 + 512 * ((uint)combinedNumber/5000))